# Alternative to offsetLeft and offsetTop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a little canvas application and finally tried to incorporate it into my blog, however now I find that on a mouse click offsetLeft and offsetRight are always 0.

I don't really know why, but how do I get that info back?

In case anyone is not seeing the tags on this post: yes I am using jQuery for mouse events.

```
$('#'+canvasId).mousedown(function(e){

    that.mouse.down = true;
    that.mouse.downx = e.pageX-this.offsetLeft;
    that.mouse.downy = e.pageY-this.offsetTop;

    that.mouse.dialogDown = k.operations.interface.getHudItem(that.mouse.downx, that.mouse.downy);

    k.operations.interface.mouseDown(that.mouse.downx, that.mouse.downy);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this work?

```
var offset = jQuery(this).css('offset');
alert( 'Left: ' + offset.left + '\nTop: ' + offset.top );
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `offset.left` and `offset.top`, not `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('#'+canvasId).mousedown(function(e){

     tt = $( this );

     tof = tt.offset()

     that.mouse.down = true;
     that.mouse.downx = e.pageX-tof.left;
     that.mouse.downy = e.pageY-tof.top;

     that.mouse.dialogDown = k.operations.interface.getHudItem(that.mouse.downx, that.mouse.downy);

k.operations.interface.mouseDown(that.mouse.downx, that.mouse.downy);
});
```